# OSX Bluetooth LE Peripheral transfer rates are slow

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

Background Info:

I've implemented a Bluetooth LE Peripheral for OSX which exposes two characteristics (using CoreBluetooth). One is readable, and one is writable (both with indications on). I've implemented a Bluetooth LE Central on iOS which will read from the readable characteristic and write to the writable characteristic. I've set it up so that every time the characteristic value is read, the value is updated (in a way [similar to this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)). The transfer rates I get with this set up are pathetically slow (topping out at a measured sustained speed of roughly 340 **bytes** / second). This speed is the actual data, and not a measure including the packet details, ACKs and so on.

Problem:

This sustained speed is too slow. I've considered two solutions:

1. There's some parameter in CoreBluetooth that I've missed that will help me increase the speed.
2. I'll need to implement a custom Bluetooth LE service using the IOBluetooth classes instead of CoreBluetooth.

I believe, I've exhausted option 1. I don't see any other parameters I can tweak. I'm limited to sending 20 bytes per message. Anything else and I get cryptic errors on the iOS device concerning Unknown Errors, Unlikely Errors, or the value being "Not Long". Since the demo project also indicates a 20 byte MTU, I'll accept that this likely isn't possible.

So I'm left with option 2. I'm trying to somehow modify the connection parameters for Bluetooth LE on OSX to hopefully allow me to increase the transfer speed (by setting the min and max conn intervals to be 20ms and 40ms respectively - as well as sending multiple BT packets per connection interval). It looks like providing my own SDP Service on IOBluetooth is the only way to achieve this on OSX. The problem with this is the documentation for how to do this is negligible to non-existent.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH216-BACIGAHC) tells me how to implement my own service (albeit using deprecate API), however, it doesn't explain the required parameters for registering an SDP service. So I'm left wondering:

1. Where can I find the required parameters for this dictionary?
2. How do I define these parameters in a way to offer a Bluetooth LE service?
3. Is there any alternative to providing a Bluetooth LE Peripheral on OSX via another framework (Python library? Linux in a VM with access to the Bluetooth stack? I'd like to avoid this altogether.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided my best course of action was to attempt to use Linux in a VM as there is more documentation available and access to the source code would hopefully guarantee that I could find a solution. For anyone who is also facing this problem, here's how you can issue a Connection Parameter Update Request on OS X (sort of).

### Step 1

Install a Linux VM. I used Virtual Box with Linux Mint 15 (64-bit Cinnamon).

### Step 2

Allow usage of the OS X Bluetooth device in your VM. Attempting to forward the Bluetooth USB Controller to your VM will give an error message. To allow this, you need to stop everything that is using the controller. On my machine, that included issuing the following commands from the command line:

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist`

This will kill the OS X Bluetooth daemon. Attempting to kill blued from the Activity Monitor will just cause it to be automatically relaunched.

`sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport`

On my MacBook, I've got a Broadcom controller and this is the kernel module that OS X uses for it. Don't worry about issuing these commands. To undo the changes, you can power down and reboot your machine (note, in some cases when playing with the BT controller and it got into a bad state, I had to actually leave the machine powered down for ~10 seconds before rebooting to clear volatile memory).

If after running these two commands you still can't mount the BT controller, you can run `kextstat | grep Bluetooth` and see other Bluetooth related kernel modules and then try to unload them as well. I've got ones named IOBluetoothFamily and IOBluetoothSerialManager that don't need to be unloaded.

### Step 3

Launch your VM and get your Linux BT stack. I checked out the bluez Git repo [from here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git). I specifically grabbed the 5.14 release tag using `git checkout tags/5.14` just to be sure it was at least a tagged version and less likely to be broken. 5.14 is the newest tag as of writing this answer.

### Step 4

Build bluez. This was done using bootstrap, then configure, then make and make install. I used the `--prefix=/opt/bluez` flag on configure to prevent overwriting the install bluetooth stack. Also, I used the `--enable-maintainer-mode` configure flag for the reason stated in the next step. You also might need to use `--disable-systemd` to get it to configure. Bluez has a bunch of tools and utilities you can use for various things. In order to use the built Bluetooth daemon, you need to stop the system daemon using `sudo service bluetooth stop`. You can then launch the built one using `sudo /opt/bluez/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d` (this launches in non-daemon mode with debug output).

### Step 5

Get your LE service running via bluez. You can view the `bluez/plugins/gatt-example.c` for how to do this. I directly modified this by removing the unnecessary code and using the battery service code as a template for my own service and characteristics. You need to recompile bluez to have this code added to the bluetooth daemon. One thing to note (that caused my a day or two of trouble getting this working) was that iOS caches the GATT service listing and this is not read/refreshed on each connection. If you add a service or characteristic or change a UUID, you'll need to disable Bluetooth on your iOS device and then re-enable it. This is undocumented in Apples docs and there is no programmatic way to do it.

### Step 6

Unfortunately, this is where things get tricky. Bluez doesn't have support built-in for issuing the Connection Parameters Update Request using any of its utilities. I had to write it myself. I'm currently seeing if they want my code to be included in the bluez stack. I can't post the code currently as I'd need to first see if the bluez devs are interested in the code and then get approval from my workplace to give the code. However, I can currently explain what I did to enable support.

### Step 7

Prime yourself on the [Bluetooth Standard](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications). Any version 4.0 or greater will have the details you need. Read the following sections.

- See Vol. 2, Part E, 4.1 for Host to Controller HCI flow.
- See Vol. 2, Part E, 5.4.2 for HCI ACL Data Packet format.
- See Vol. 3, Part A, 4 for Signalling Packet format.
- See Vol. 3, Part A, 4.20 for Connection Parameter Update Request format.

You're basically going to need to write the code to format the packets and then write them to the hci device. The HCI ACL Data Packet header will contain 4 bytes. This is followed by 4 bytes for the Signalling command's length and channel id. This is then followed by your signal payload which in my case was 12 bytes (for the Connection Parameter Update Request).

You can then write them to the device similar to `hci_send_cmd` in `bluez/lib/hci.c`. I did each packet header as it's own struct and wrote them each as `iovec`s to the device. I put my new function in the hci.c file and exposed it with a function prototype in `bluez/lib/hci_lib.h`. I then modified `bluez/tools/hcitool.c` to allow me to call this method from the command line. In my case, I made it so that the command was nearly identical to the lecup command as it requires the same parameters (lecup can't be used as it's meant to be called on the master side, not the slave).

Recompiled all of this and then, voila, I can use my new command on hcitool to send the parameters to the bluetooth controller. After sending my command, it then re-negotiates with the iOS device as expected.

### Comments

This process is not for the faint of heart. Hopefully, either this, or some other method of setting the connection parameters is added to bluez to simplify this process. Ideally, Apple will allow the ability to do so via CoreBluetooth or IOBluetooth at some point as well (it could be possible, but undocumentated / difficult to do so, I gave up with the Apple libraries). I've journeyed down the rabbit hole and learned much more about the Bluetooth Spec then I thought I'd have to to simply change the connection parameters between a MacBook and an iPhone. Hopefully this will be helpful to *somebody* at some point (even if it's me checking back on how I did this).

I know I've left out a lot of details in this in order to keep it somewhat brief (i.e. usage on the bluez tools). Please comment if something isn't clear.

Comment: Hello @Sandy,

Thanks a lot for this detailed process !

From what I understand, you were able to issue the Connection Parameters Update Request from a bluez-based slave peripheral, without any kernel modification ?

(In the following discussion, the conclusion was that it wasn't possible without a kernel module : https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno/issues/38 )

We tried to forged the ACL packet and send it through the L2CAP socket, but this didn't work...
Would your code be available somewhere ? (the bluez/lib/hci.c new method in particular...)

Comment: @neyric : I was able to issue the Connection Parameters Update Request from bluez on a Linux VM. At the time, I offered my code to the bluez mailing list but received no interest in it ([see my posts here](http://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=139203542730183&w=2)). I've just given your github posts a look over and you've come to the right conclusion that the lecup is only for updates from the central side. Peripheral connection updates required building and sending a packet via HCI. I've got the code stashed away somewhere. I'll see if I can dig it up for you.

Comment: @neyric : I've uploaded a patch of my code changes. Not sure if all of them are needed or not, but I hope it's helpful. It's off of the 5.14 version of bluez so I'd recommend checking out 5.14, applying the patch and then pulling whatever newer tag of bluez you want to use. [Patch here](https://gist.github.com/SandyChapman/4a64c9ea22cd27d935e3).

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing your Peripheral using CoreBluetooth, you can request somewhat customized connection parameters by calling [`-[CBPeripheralManager setDesiredConnectionLatency:forCentral:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW29) to Low, Medium, or High (where Low latency means higher bandwidth). The documentation does not specify what this means, so we have to test it ourselves.

On an OSX Peripheral, when you set the desired latency to Low, the interval is still 22.5ms which is far from the minimum of 7.5ms.

- On OSX Yosemite 10.10.4, this is what the CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency values mean:

  - **Low**: Min Interval: 18 (22.5ms), Max Interval: 18 (22.5ms), Slave Latency: 4 events, Timeout: 200 (2s).
  - **Medium**: Min Interval: 32 (40ms), Max Interval: 32 (40ms), Slave Latency: 6 events, Timeout: 200 (2s)
  - **High**: Min Interval: 160 (200ms), Max Interval: 160 (200ms), Slave Latency: 2 events, Timeout: 300 (3s)

Here is the code that I used to run a CBPeripheralManager on OSX. I used an Android device as central using [BLE Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexodus.bleexplorer) and [dumped the Bluetooth traffic to a Btsnoop file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic).

```
// clang main.m -framework Foundation -framework IOBluetooth
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <IOBluetooth/IOBluetooth.h>

@interface MyPeripheralManagerDelegate: NSObject<CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) CBPeripheralManager* peripheralManager;
@property (nonatomic) CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency nextLatency;
@end
@implementation MyPeripheralManagerDelegate
+ (NSString*)stringFromCBPeripheralManagerState:(CBPeripheralManagerState)state {
    switch (state) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff: return @"PoweredOff";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn: return @"PoweredOn";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting: return @"Resetting";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized: return @"Unauthorized";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown: return @"Unknown";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported: return @"Unsupported";
    }
}
+ (CBUUID*)LatencyCharacteristicUuid {
    return [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"B81672D5-396B-4803-82C2-029D34319015"];
}
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"CBPeripheralManager entered state %@", [MyPeripheralManagerDelegate stringFromCBPeripheralManagerState:peripheral.state]);
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSDictionary* dict = @{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"ConnLatencyTest"};
        // Generated with uuidgen
        CBUUID *serviceUuid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"7AE48DEE-2597-4B4D-904E-A3E8C7735738"];
        CBMutableService* service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:serviceUuid primary:TRUE];
        // value:nil makes it a dynamic-valued characteristic
        CBMutableCharacteristic* latencyCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:MyPeripheralManagerDelegate.LatencyCharacteristicUuid properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
        service.characteristics = @[latencyCharacteristic];
        [self.peripheralManager addService:service];
        [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:dict];
        NSLog(@"startAdvertising. isAdvertising: %d", self.peripheralManager.isAdvertising);
    }
}
- (void)peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
                                       error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error advertising: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSLog(@"peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising %d", self.peripheralManager.isAdvertising);

}
+ (CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency) nextLatencyAfter:(CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency)latency {
    switch (latency) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyLow: return CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyMedium;
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyMedium: return CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyHigh;
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyHigh: return CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyLow;
    }
}
+ (NSString*)describeLatency:(CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency)latency {
    switch (latency) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyLow: return @"Low";
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyMedium: return @"Medium";
        case CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyHigh: return @"High";
    }
}
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request {
    if ([request.characteristic.UUID isEqualTo:MyPeripheralManagerDelegate.LatencyCharacteristicUuid]) {
        [self.peripheralManager setDesiredConnectionLatency:self.nextLatency forCentral:request.central];
        NSString* description = [MyPeripheralManagerDelegate describeLatency: self.nextLatency];
        request.value = [description dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
        NSLog(@"didReceiveReadRequest:latencyCharacteristic. Responding with %@", description);
        self.nextLatency = [MyPeripheralManagerDelegate nextLatencyAfter:self.nextLatency];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"didReceiveReadRequest: (unknown) %@", request);
    }
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyPeripheralManagerDelegate *peripheralManagerDelegate = [[MyPeripheralManagerDelegate alloc] init];
        CBPeripheralManager* peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:peripheralManagerDelegate queue:nil];
        peripheralManagerDelegate.peripheralManager = peripheralManager;
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```