# packets sent via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, packet

Is there a way to find out what packets being sent by android to paired bluteooth devices? For example what packets being sent if an incoming call is detected?
Update: Im using an Android 2.3 device, so the built-in logger of android 4.4 is not available for me. Moreover i cant find an app that logs the bluetooth traffic on my older device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)

Answer (score 0):

What about writing what you receive somewhere? Like on a text file? Or in the SQLite DB? Or even in a view you put somewhere in your app for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture logs sent by one Bluetooth device to another, you will need tools like Bluetooth Protocol Analyzer tool like `Sodera Analyzers` (http://www.fte.com/products/sodera.aspx). But such tools are very costly.

You may also go for the logs of interaction between Bluetooth host and controller i.e. HCI(Host Controller Interface) snoop logs. 
To enable HCI logs on android, Go to Dev. Options->Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log.