# Bluetooth HCI snoop log not generated

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat, android-bluetooth, s5

I'm running Android 4.4.2 and I enabled the "Bluetooth HCI snoop log" as described here [Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic/23900782#23900782)

After turning bluetooth on and off I rebooted the phone. I could not find the log file in the expected location:

```
$ adb pull /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log
remote object '/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log' does not exist
```

How can I get to the btsnoop_hci.log?

Comment: The answer marked as correct is not actually the correct answer. Please scroll to the highest voted answer for the ACTUAL correct answer.

Comment: Try this for android O, samsung latest: `adb pull /data/log/bt/btsnoop_hci.log`

Answer (score 140):

UPDATE: The btsnoop hci log seems to be getting phased out of the user-accessible areas on a lot of phones. Assuming you have hci logging enabled, you can get a bugreport

```
adb bugreport anewbugreportfolder
```

Then decompress the folder. If you're lucky there is an 'FS' folder that contains the btsnoop_hci.log log several layers down (not sure why some phones have this and some don't.) If you don`t have it, grab the bug report text file that looks like this

```
bugreport-2018-08-01-15-08-01.txt
```

Run btsnooz.py against it. [Per Google`s instructions,](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-bug-reports)

```
To extract snoop logs from the bug report, use the btsnooz script.

Get btsnooz.py.
Extract the text version of the bug report.
Run btsnooz.py on the text version of the bug report:

btsnooz.py BUG_REPORT.txt > BTSNOOP.log
```

As of 1/12/21 the link to btsnooz is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/+/refs/heads/master/system/tools/scripts/btsnooz.py

LEGACY ANSWER:

You can see where your phone is storing the hci log by reading the bt_stack.conf file. Try

```
adb shell cat /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf
```

You will see a line that looks like

```
# BtSnoop log output file
BtSnoopFileName =/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log <--your file location
```

It is usually, but not always (depends on the phone) on the root of the sdcard. There is also a line in this configuration file which may reflect if hci logging is actually on or not

```
# EnableBtSnoop logging function
# valid value : true , false
BtSnoopLogOutput=false
```

Toggling the 'Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log' option in the developer options should change it to

```
# EnableBtSnoop logging function
# valid value : true , false
BtSnoopLogOutput=true
```

I say "should" because for some phones this doesn't update this file. You should:

1. Read the bt_stack.conf file. See where the HCI log should be and if bt snoop logging is actually enabled or not
2. If developer options say btsnoop_hci logging is on but the bt_stack.conf file says it is off, try power cycling bluetooth and/or your phone.
3. If your phone is rooted, manually set `BtSnoopLogOutput=true`

If none of the 3 options work, you're out of luck. BT Snoop hci logging is a bit inconsistent across different phones. I've seen a few phones where I just couldn't get it to work not matter what but for the most cases you should be able to get it going. A rooted phone is not a requirement.

Comment: How can i set set BtSnoopLogOutput=true on a rooted phone?

Comment: Easiest way would be pull the bt_stack.conf file and then just change 'False' to 'True' in a text editor, then push it back to the correct directory. Note you will probably need to change directory permissions on the phone filesystem to push it back on, which shouldn`t be a problem if you are rooted.

Comment: Mine says **BtSnoopLogOutput=false**.  How to make it **true**?

Comment: Google Pixel seems to be stuck on `BtSnoopLogOutput=false`

Comment: Some other places you may find the `bt_stack.conf` file are `/system/etc/` and `/vendor/etc/`

Comment: I found mine in the bugreport zip at: `FS\data\misc\bluetooth\logs`

Comment: Full fail: my lineageos 16.0 on a s7 hasn't any of the `Bt*` values set and changing the config results in `adb: error: failed to copy 'bt_stack.conf' to '/etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
`

Comment: @Blightbuster same as you on LineageOS it's on `/data/misc/bluetooth/logs/btsnoop_hci.log`

Comment: If you go the `btsnooz.py` route, note that it's a python2 script. It took me a while to notice. The error related to running with python3 is: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"

Comment: I followed these instructions but Wireshark was unable to analyze the log file created. Has the btsnoop format been changed? (S7 Edge, Android 8.0.0)

Comment: @JasonSteele I was able to use the current (top) instructions and read the log with Wireshark in October. Pixel 2, Android 11. It seems like an unlikely area to make a change since the format is standardized (RFC 1761) and it's not really user facing. Have you verified that there actually was output in the file?

Comment: @user3067860 yes, a file was generated. I have a link to it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3544DrhPbI9YxktL6rSWkpAe-YeoPn4/view?usp=sharing. I agree that it does sound odd but then I also read somewhere about BlueZ changing (or adding) to the format.

Comment: Thanks, "updated answer" was the only solution worked for me on Android 11 OnePlus 6 device.

Answer (score 18):

On Nexus 5X and Pixel C Android O you have to enable bluetooth, enable HCI snooping in developer settings, disable and reenable bluetooth and reboot.

After that you can get the log by going to developer settings and "take bug report" and get a full log.

The file bt_stack.conf is not changed and there is no new file on /sdcard as on other devices

Comment: I can confirm that this is the only method that works for me. I'm using the Pixel 2 XL on Android 8.1 Oreo. The "take bug report" feature generates an archive and the log file will be in that archive under _FS/data/misc/bluetooth/logs/btsnoop_hci.log_

Comment: This is really the most consistent of the methods that works without any rooting, USB connection, etc. and on the most phones.

Comment: This worked for my Samsung Galaxy S7. The bug report contains a file FS/data/log/bt/btsnoop_hci.log that can be opened with WireShark.

Comment: Are you sure you need to reboot? It works for me without doing that.

Answer (score 11):

For a user version Pixel/Nexus, you may not have the permission to pull out /data/misc/bluetooth/logs/btsnoop_hci.log.
You can get the hci log like this:

```
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
adb bugreport > BUG_REPORT.txt
```

You will get a BUG_REPORT.txt and zip file. HCI log will be found under FS\data\misc\bluetooth\logs of the zip file.

Comment: adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
;                                                  
                                                         
adb bugreport > BUG_REPORT.txt

Comment: This just made the `btsnoop_hci.log` appear on my Mi 9.

Comment: works also for moto g6 with Android 9, thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

On a OnePlus 6 (A6003, Android 9) phone (and I believe other OnePlus phones) the location is:

`/sdcard/oem_log/btsnoop`

This location does not require rooting nor accessing through `adb`. The log will have a `.cfa` extension and is in a binary `pcap` format suitable for analysis with e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Yes, but it is still not readable. Did you do something with this logs? it isn't utf-8 and i can't decode that with any coding format. i have only ```IQOS 2.4 ?????[][]????``` etc. How to read that?! One plus 7 pro

Comment: @Kamil This is a binary format (`pcap`) which you can analyse with e.g. Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) by simply opening the file. I added this to my answer.

Comment: Okay i got it. I just was sure that its plaintext logs. Thank you very much.

Comment: OMG dude, thanks so much! I'm exactly with an OP6 and the file is right there as you said. Why is the location not standard?

Comment: It is not there on my OnePlus 6P Android 11

Answer (score 6):

This is what solved it for me:

1)`adb shell cat /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf`

to see what is the log file name, for me it is :

```
/data/log/bt/btsnoop_hci.log
```

The tricky part is that files get generated with timestamp in their names so you won't be able to get them(it) just by using

```
adb pull /data/log/bt/btsnoop_hci.log
```

2)Use `adb pull /data/log/bt/` instead, and you will get the whole folder, with all logs

Answer (score 4):

On mine, bt_stack.conf showed /sdcard/Android/data/btsnoop_hci.log

Comment: Every device could be different.  Location of this log file is specified in **/etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf**

Answer (score 3):

For Samsung s8, the magic location is /data/log/bt/ 
and you can get it if you take a bugreport

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but see also PaulFreund's answer for non-rooting solution.

Answer (score 1):

On a **Xiaomi POCO X3** (MIUI) (may be only Poco X3)

Enable developer mode and HCI log.

1. Call `* # * # 284 # * # *`
2. Apply
3. Explore the folder at `/MIUI/debug_log/`
4. Copy `bugreport-******.zip` to PC
5. Unzip the archive to a new folder
6. Find at the new folder another ZIP archive and unzip it
7. Find log and Wireshark format files (cfa) in `FS\data\misc\bluetooth\logs`

Answer (score 0):

@TwinPrimesAreEz is excellent but there is a fourth option; at least when your device is rooted. Call:

```
/system/bin/btsnoop
```

[Somewhere](https://sourceforge.net/p/android-x86/system_bt/ci/48d70a4e6fad28d7434b33cd7559175af60b9e59/) this tool was removed but it still exists on my device. Whatismore, it seems to be called when bluetooth is enabled. In `logcat` I see: "btsnoop_dump: : snoop_log_open: Unable to open the Dir entry". Not sure why it is unable to open that dir (btw, it is `/data/media/0`) But I suspect that this tool somehow interferes with the new HCI snooping option integrated into Android. But if you call that tool directly (e.g. via `adb shell` or [Terminal emulator](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqo4y3jorZAhUHbFAKHRFDDrUQFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Djackpal.androidterm%26hl%3Den)) it works. For me it created file `/data/media/0/hci_snoop20180203164422.cfa`.

Comment: @Mans: Yes, you can open it using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

All the above were helpful -- on an S8 and Windows 10, the option from Fukai/Rene about using the bug report was the best for me.  (Slightly different file path, but the zip file did have the log in it.)

However, I later noticed that I got a NOTIFICATION in Android to "SHARE YOUR BUG REPORT", and when I selected the notification I had options to email/save to G Drive/etc.  Emailed the txt and zip to myself, and that was that, skipping adb and the other rigmarole.

Answer (score 0):

On redmi note 7 I found log directly on phon in location:

/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/debug_log/common/btsnoop_hci_20220416214313.cfa

using search, I have written "bt" and found theae files!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my old Samsung A5 (SM-A520F) it worked when turning on the HCI snooping in the developer settings and then rebooting. Then finally, the log files were contained in the bugreport generated via `adb bugreport`.