# Bluetooth HCI snoop log doesn't work on Nexus 6P

Tags: android, logging, bluetooth, hci, snoop

I'm trying to use "Bluetooth HCI snoop log" on my Nexus 6P with Android 7.1.2 but even if the option is enabled in the developer option it doesn't work. In fact, the option inside the *bt_stack.conf* is disabled.

```
adb shell head  /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf

# Enable BtSnoop configuration from this config file
# Snoop is enabled by default on userdebug builds, below configuration
# enables to override it and take effect from the configurations here.
BtSnoopConfigFromFile=false

# Enable BtSnoop logging function
# valid value : true, false
BtSnoopLogOutput=false
BtSnoopExtDump=false
```

Anyone has encountered this issue?

Comment: Same issue over here. Can't get it to work on Nexus 5X and/or Pixel running 7.1.2. [This issue over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445552/bluetooth-hci-snoop-log-not-generated) gives some insight on the matter.