# What's the purpose of "Bluetooth snoop logging" option on Android Wear devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

It's in the wearable's `Settings` menu, in the `Developers Options` section. I couldn't find any information about it, nothing [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) either.

What are the potential use case scenarios of this feature?

[image]

Note: to unlock the `Developers Options` section, tap 7 times on the `About` item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a log file of all the Bluetooth traffic to and from your device, for analysis purposes.

Edit: Adding @BrentM's comment:

> The log file is saved to /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log. Take a look at this question, it is not specifically for wear, but wear should follow the same work flow: [Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-b%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bluetooth-traffic)

Comment: Thanks. Where is it stored?

Comment: @EyesClear The log file is saved to **/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log**. Take a look at this question, it is not specifically for wear, but wear should follow the same work flow: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)