# BLE app storing and retrieving data using some database

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to store the logs of a connected device in BLE android app in android studio ? Does it use sqlite or something else ? steps will be really helpful , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

- If you'd like to store the raw BLE log on Android:

  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic).
- If you wish to just read/write/receive notifications from a BLE peripheral device:

  On your app, once you have found the device you wish to connect to, you will run something similar to `gattInstance = device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)`, where `gattCallback` is an instance of class `BluetoothGattCallback`.

  This instance is where you get a handle of all the data from BLE. You may use `onCharacteristicRead(...)` and `onCharacteristicChanged(...)` to process the data received form the device.

  All of this information is available on the Android documentation, [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot , but i wanted to store the BLE device's data like the readings on it , not just a normal bluetooth connection .

Comment: I do not understand your question. The method I present above works for Bluetooth Low Energy as well.

So you want to log the received packet on the application? What OS are you developing for?

Comment: I am developing on android studio and I wanted to log some data from a ble device into a database . By log I meant the general information of the device or readings and not packets , dont want to decipher the packet data .

Comment: If I understood correctly, you wish to collect data from a BLE device that is connected to the Android device. And once you receive such data you want to add it to a database. Is this it?

Comment: @MahimaMakhija I have edited my original answer. Please check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) @AmiguelS

Comment: I read the documentation you stated above , that helps but one more thing once i read the characteristic/data how do i put the same into the database , does BLE app use the default sqlite database ? or do i need to do add some other code ?

Comment: @MahimaMakhija BLE does not use any database at all. In the methods I stated, you receive an array of bytes containing the characteristics value. You can do with it what ever you please.