# Reading sensor data sent by bluetooth into browser

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth, sensors, web-bluetooth

I am working on a React app that will make use of 3 sensor data values in real time.

The data is sent through bluetooth from an nRF52840 chip.

At first I tried the [Noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) library for bluetooth and it worked right away with minimal code: [Noble bluetooth code](https://codeshare.io/am8n9X)

The result of running the code above looked like this: [image: Sensor data logging]

However when I tried to integrate Noble into my React app I got errors with dependencies when Webpack was making a dll so I did not find a way to integrate it.

I tried the Web Bluetooth API instead using the example here: [Web Bluetooth heart rate sensor](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos/blob/gh-pages/heart-rate-sensor/heartRateSensor.js)
I tried it out using a Polar H10 I have and that worked well, then I modified it to work with my sensor.

Now I can read sensor values into the browser, but I know they are the wrong values.. they are always around 50-60 ish and do not change as I change the sensor.

I am thinking I need some parsing code, like the heart rate sensor code. However that code is using bit-level & operations, flags and it is assuming little-endian data. I do not know if my data is little endian or not or other bit-level details so I would rather not write parsing code.

I know that Noble for example can read it out of the box so I want something similar, is this possible? Is there some kind of bluetooth standard for reading the data or is this hardware specific? There is no documentation on my hardware so I can't read about it.
Here is the code I am currently using, similar to the heart rate sensor code: [Bluetooth sensor reading code](https://codeshare.io/an4b9V)

Answer (score 1):

There are standard [Bluetooth services & characteristics](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services), but any hardware may choose (or need) to use custom methods.  There is no standard then, not even encoding style such as little/big endian or bytes vs strings.

Options to understand the data are to use tools that can read the data in multiple formats, such as [HCI logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic), [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Nordic-mobile-Apps/nRF-Connect-for-mobile-previously-called-nRF-Master-Control-Panel) ([desktop](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF-Connect-for-desktop)), or Chrome's `chrome://bluetooth-internals`.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. I managed to find out it was sending ASCII code as a comma separated string of values. That made it fairly easy to write some parsing code. I should maybe have guessed when the values were mostly similar values around 48-57 (the ASCII representation of numbers).