# sniffing bluetooth low energy in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sniffing

I wanted to test my microchip beacon setup.. Is there any way to verify the advertisements sent by the beacon are received by Android without writing an application.

I have seen stackoverflow post related to sniffing where you have to enable bluetooth sniffing in Developer options

[Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)

Will this apply to Bluetooth Low Energy Module also or is it only for Bluetooth Classic Devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will pick up everything on the HCI link, including BLE advertisements. But you must have at least one app that has told the system to perform a BLE scan of course.

Why don't you just use a BLE scan app like nRF Connect?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of BLE sniffer apps in the Android marketplace that will pickup and display your beacon advertisement. Search for "ble sniffer"