# How to sniff Bluetooth htc packages using androids feature

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, sniffing

I'd like to monitor my bluetooth traffic on my andorid device.
I have tried this stuff:
[Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)

But sady, i still cant find the saved file. The only File I can find is in the /sdcard/Android/data/ folder.  But this file is empty and old.

I turned bt off to switch the tracking functionality on and turned it on again when started. Same when i was finished.

Oh, and its said that the phone doesnt need to be rooted. I've found an app which does the same but needs the phone to be rooted... so maybe i also need to root it to make the androids built in feature work?

And I tried this on an s10 and s7.

I hope someone can help me out here.
Have a nice day and thanks for reading :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sniffing/logging your own Android Bluetooth traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)