# How to control shutter switches via bluetooth

Tags: android, go, automation, bluetooth, shutter

I have electric shutter switches (schneider electric, Model: DT1_IT10) that can be controled with an android app via bluetooth (You connect them by long-pressing on the shutter switch and then add them on the phone). I thought that when the app can control them, i can control them, too. So i want to write a remote control in GO.

But i dont have any experience and just need a starting point. So the questions are:

1. Is this even possible? Maybe the Bluetooth connection is secured?
2. How and where do i get informations about how to connect to such a device? I couldnt find any information on the manufacturer page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The magics of free software (as in freedom, not beer) enables us to do whatever we want with the things we own. Protect FOSS, protect our freedom.

Political agenda aside, to answer your questions:

1. Bluetooth connections are secured, yes. But that does not mean we can't peek and see how they work.
2. I would start by sniffing the connections (see [this](https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-capture-bluetooth-traffic-tcpdump-linux) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic)) and dumping whatever traffic is going through. While doing that, I'd check some libraries for bluetooth in Go ([this](https://github.com/muka/go-bluetooth) and [this](https://github.com/tinygo-org/bluetooth) might give you a good idea on that).

It'll not be easy (I've done a few things like that in the past) but if you're into that kind of thing, it'll definitely be fun :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips!! 
So in my head it would be like: connect bt dongle with shutter switch -> dump/sniff a very specific Bluetooth traffic snippet lets say the "command to turn the shutter up" -> then pass these "lines" via go program to the bluetooth device and tell it to send to the switch

Comment: A bit simplified but yes. You'd need to [do the handshake and find the right mode](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/all) with the bluetooth device and figure out the messages that are being passed to the device, basically