# Bluetooth LE, unknown device settings

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothlescanner

I have a bluetooth device that is measuring the force and basically sends one single value. There is an android app to connect to it, but I would like to develop my own since I would like to add some features. I managed to connect to it, but don't know which service or characteristics is the one that has the number I need. Someone could maybe know which of these it could be?

Service 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

```
Characteristics:
|--00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Service 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

```
Characteristics:
|--00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
|--00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
|--00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Service a9712440-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66

```
Characteristics:
|--a9712441-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9712442-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9712443-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
```

Service a970fd30-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66

```
Characteristics:
|--a970fd31-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd32-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd33-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd34-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd35-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd36-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd37-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd38-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd39-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd3a-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a970fd3b-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
```

Service a9717260-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66

```
Characteristics:
|--a9717261-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717262-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717263-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717264-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717265-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717266-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717267-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717268-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a9717269-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a971726a-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a971726b-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a971726c-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
|--a971726d-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66
```

Answer (score 2):

The first two services are Generic Access & Generic Attribute. You can find the UUIDs in the assigned 16-bit numbers document [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/assigned-numbers/). Just search for their short version 0x1800 and 0x1801. The other three are not defined in the standard and are custom services defined by the manufacturer.

I searched online for one of the UUIDs and found them in the [B24 Telemetry Technical Manual](https://www.vetek.com/Dynamics/Documents/247291d1-f6d2-40cc-abbe-29431c3d3a14/Technical_manual_B24_V1%20ENG.pdf) which contains this quick overview (Appendix A):

| ID | Description | Type | Format | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a970fd30** | **Configuration Profile** | **Service** | **-** | **-** | **-** |
| a970fd31 | Data Rate | Characteristic | Uint32 | 0 | 10000 |
| a970fd32 | Resolution | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 64 |
| a970fd33 | Battery Threshold | Characteristic | Float | 2.3 | 3.5 |
| a970fd34 | View PIN | Characteristic | String | 4 | 4 bytes |
| a970fd35 | Serial Number | Characteristic | Uint32 | Read Only |  |
| a970fd36 | Data Tag | Characteristic | Uint16 | 0 | 0xFFFF |
| a970fd37 | Battery Value | Characteristic | Float | Read Only |  |
| a970fd38 | System Zero | Characteristic | Float | -FLT_MAX | FLT_MAX |
| a970fd39 | Configuration PIN | Characteristic | Uint32 | 0 | 4294967295 |
| a970fd3a | Model Name | Characteristic | String | Read Only |  |
| a970fd3b | Firmware Version | Characteristic | Float | Read Only |  |
| **a9712440** | **Data Profile** | **Service** | **-** | **-** | **-** |
| a9712441 | Status | Characteristic | Uint8 | Read Only |  |
| a9712442 | Data Value | Characteristic | Float | Read Only |  |
| a9712443 | Data Units | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 255 |
| **a9717260** | **Calibration Profile** | **Service** | **-** | **-** | **-** |
| a9717261 | Sensitivity Range | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 3 |
| a9717262 | Coefficient (@Index) | Characteristic | Float | -FLT_MAX | FLT_MAX |
| a9717263 | Linearisation Index | Characteristic | Uint8 |  |  |
| a9717264 | Linearisation Repeat | Characteristic | Uint8 | 3 | 11 |
| a9717265 | Linearisation Points | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 15 |
| a9717266 | Base Value | Characteristic | Float | Read Only |  |
| a9717267 | Base Units | Characteristic | Uint8 | Read Only |  |
| a9717268 | Data Gain | Characteristic | Float | -FLT_MAX | FLT_MAX |
| a9717269 | Data Offset | Characteristic | Float | -FLT_MAX | FLT_MAX |
| a971726a | Calibration PIN | Characteristic | Uint32 | 0 | 4294967295 |
| a971726b | Calibration Units | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 255 |
| a971726c | Advanced Index | Characteristic | Uint8 | 0 | 255 |
| a971726d | Advanced Data | Characteristic | Byte | Array | unknown |

You can find even more detailed information for each characteristic in this document as well as a description on how to connect:

> - Scan for devices
> - Select required corresponding device MAC address and connect
> - Send the Configuration PIN to characteristic a970fd39-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66 attributed to
>   service a970fd30-a0e8-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66.
> - Read required aspects and configure as appropriate.
> - Disconnect to allow device to resume transmitting advertising packets

Comment: Thank you. Very detailed answer and a good link to the documentation. It is a B24 device. However, I cannot connect since I don't have the configuration pin of the device, and the default of 0 is not working. I have the key used to add sensor to the official app, but I don't know if it can be converted to 16bit int. ( code is 2x 6 characters - TT0LAC-44HS3Q ). Guess I need to try to get it from the device manufacturers.

Comment: Glad it is helpful to you! One way of figuring this out would be to analyze the BLE connection using a BLE sniffer or by using your phones log capabilities (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic) for example).